# Get InnerHTML of Changing Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, innerhtml

I have a `<div>` that contains different content all the time.

```
<div ng-html="day.content" class="day_content"></div>
```

For example, the `<div>` could be updated to

```
<div ng-html="day.content" class="day_content">1</div>
```

or

```
<div ng-html="day.content" class="day_content">2</div>
```

or

```
<div ng-html="day.content" class="day_content">3</div>
```

When I try and get the `innerHTML` of this `<div>`, it always gives me `<div ng-html="day.content" class="day_content"></div>`.

It doesn't matter if I use jQuery's `.html()` or JavaScript's `document.getElementById().innerHTML`.

Why can't I get the innerHTML of the `<div>` that is updated with data?

Comment: When are you getting the html. Also do you have duplicate ids in html??

Comment: It sounds like you are selecting a parent of the element you actually want.

Comment: I'm using `setTimeout(function() {
        }, 1000);`

Comment: Could you post your JS or create a fiddle which replicates your issue?

Comment: @ChrisSpittles I'm not sure how to replicate "injected" data. Everything works fine when the data is hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to get the value that is in the div, and trying to store it in Javascript? If so try  declaring a variable in the Javascript to store the value, e.g.

var day = document.getElementById("day_content").value;

This variable will now store the value of this div.
Correct me if I'm wrong - Good Luck ^_-

Comment: OP I really hope you didn't downvote this. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lq7c4ej6/, it shows that this is the correct answer. However, it looks like you're using AngularJS, and surely there's a more robust way, native Angular way (perhaps taking advantage of data-binding?) to get the value you need. EDIT: fixed JSfiddle link

Comment: I didn't downvote, though it's not correct since I'm using classes.

Comment: The problem is not the initial innerHTML, but rather the "injected" values.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I misread that. The jsfiddle above has the correct answer then.

Comment: @MimiLauren No it doesn't. The problem is not the initial innerHTML, but rather the "injected" values.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery then 
   $('.day_content').html();

Comment: I clearly wrote "It doesn't matter if I use jQuery's .html() or JavaScript's document.getElementById().innerHTML."